# How to display *.jp2 using ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I have a [*.jp2 file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i4ZEmNYlMBpherPDhlMWKbSNE_9RI_gm/view?usp=sharing) ([direct link if you need it](https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1i4ZEmNYlMBpherPDhlMWKbSNE_9RI_gm)) and I need to display it as a layer using [ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/).

I have tried to convert it into COGeoTIFF using OSGeo4W (gdal)

`gdal_translate -of COG NC_2022-12-17.jp2 result.tif`
And it looks like it became COD. [This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I49dT.png) of `gdalinfo`.

After that I have tried to use it with the [Imagery Tile Layer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/layers-imagerytilelayer-cog/).

But it is not visible on the map. There are no errors in the console.

On the other hand, if I use the file from the example for Imagery Tile Layer ([this one](https://ss6imagery.arcgisonline.com/imagery_sample/landsat8/Bolivia_LC08_L1TP_001069_20190719_MS.tiff)) it works perfectly fine.

So, the issue is not in the code.
How do I display the provided *.jp2 file on the map?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue.
I simply had to update GDAL to 3.6.2 and it worked.

```
gdal_translate -ot UInt16 -of COG MSAVIC_2022-12-17.jp2 result.tif
```

This does the trick